# Spring batch retry problem in case of customListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a customWriterListener which implements the default `ItemWriteListener`. As part of `afterWrite` and `onWriteError` methods I update the success and failure counts of items in my table for the job.

```
public class CustomItemWriterListener implements ItemWriteListener<Item> {

  @Override
  public void afterWrite(List<? extends Item> items) {
    long failureCount = items.stream().filter(Item::hasErrors).count();
    long successCount = items.size() - failureCount;
    incrementCountsInDb(failureCount, successCount);
  }

  @Override
  public void onWriteError(Exception exception, List<? extends Item> items) {
    int failureCount = items.size();
    int successCount = 0
    incrementCountsInDb(failureCount, successCount);
  }
}
```

Now I have configured my retries like this.

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("testStep")
            .<String, Object>chunk(10)
            .reader(customReader()) 
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(customWriter())
            .faultTolerant()
            .retry(DataAccessException.class)
            .retryLimit(3)
            .build();
```

If my chunk of 1000 records fail for the first time because of DataAccessException, failure and success counts is updated as 1000 and 0 as part of `onWriteError` method execution. Now the chunk gets retried, if the chunk is successful this time, the success count is 1000 and failure count is also 1000 as it was updated as part of first time failure. But ideally final count should be success - 1000 and failure - 0 since chunk was successfully processed after retries.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the issue. Can you share your listener and a minimal example that shows the issue? Are you expecting the listener to be aware of the retries? If this is the case, I think it should also implement `RetryListener`.

Comment: Apologies for the long delay @MahmoudBenHassine. Didn't notice this comment somehow. I have updated the question with some extra info. Yes RetryListener seems to make some sense. Any extra inputs on using it for above problem ?